# Service Oriented Architecture (SOA): One Database or Multiple Databases?

Tags: design, database-design, microservices, soa, .net-core

In Service Oriented Architecture (SOA), should there be One Single Database "with the share as much as possible philosophy" or Multiple Databases by Service/functional area?

I know in Microservices, the hard rule is to apply one database per area.

Just curious if the hard rule applies to SOA?

This is not opinion based: Just curious if there is a hard rule to SOA Architecture principles, if multiple databases allowed or not. Similar to SOLID Principles.

Comment: There's no SOA vs Microservices. So the question does not make much sense. MS architectural style is an implementation of SOA (well, sort of).

Comment: It is not the number of databases, it is that external consumers (i.e. applications and also other services) shall not reach around the service to access service data directly from the database, but instead ask the service for the data of interest.  This allows the service to refactor its data at will and supports modular architecture.

Comment: To be clear, **there is no hard rule;** there are only possible consequences.  It doesn't suddenly become "not SOA" if you decide, for purely pragmatic reasons, that you want two services to share a settings database, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Although SOA does not have a unanimously accepted definition, I would like to quote Udi Dahan here, see [original article](http://udidahan.com/2014/03/31/on-that-microservices-thing/). Mr. Dahan also has a great definition for a service:

> A service is the technical authority of a business capability.

Elaborating on that definition, since a service should be the authority of a business capability, it should own its data - i.e. have its own database. This does not always mean a separate physical instance, logical separation such as a different schema that is only accessible to the service in question suffices as well.

I like to think of this in terms of keeping well defined boundaries for a service. Sharing data is akin to unclear boundaries and hence tight coupling with another service. Logically separating the datastore is the pragmatic approach to ensure your overall system can follow an evolutionary architecture.

Answer (score 0):

In the book [*SOA Principles of Service Design*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B009NG7UWI), Thomas Erl defines 8 principles of service orientation.  One of these is ['Service Autonomy'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_autonomy_principle).  This is subdivided into runtime and design autonomy.  For example, you could define a specific schema for each service but deploy these to a shared database.  That's design autonomy but not runtime autonomy.

In the section 'Pure Autonomy' Erl states: "The ideal implementation environment for a service is one where it has absolute onwership of its runtime existence and we have top-to-bottom governance over its design and architecture."<sup>1</sup>

The book above and in other writings on SOA, autonomy is considered to be generally beneficial but it does have some trade-offs such as cost.  Unfortunately, the popular idea of SOA became associated with SOAP (unrelated acronym) and WS* and few people bothered to read this or any of the other serious literature about SOA.  Basically all the concepts associated with microservices was described in this book long before the term become common.

I tend to agree with the emphasized section [mine] from the Martin Fowler article on [Microservices](https://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html):

> This common manifestation of SOA has led some microservice advocates to reject the SOA label entirely, although ***others consider microservices to be one form of SOA, perhaps service orientation done right***. Either way, the fact that SOA means such different things means it's valuable to have a term that more crisply defines this architectural style.

<sup>1</sup> Page 308, "SOA Principles of Service Design"; Thomas Erl 2008.

Answer (score 0):

## Cart Horse, Horse Cart

Is a database shared between services, or owned by a single service? **Wrong question.**

What is a service? **Better Question.**

What does it mean to have a good SOA implementation? **Good Question.**

Answer that and you will have already answered the question about databases.

---

A Service (at least as far as SOA is concerned) is a single cohesive piece of business functionality. The one stop shop for that particular set of behaviours.

Now we get down into the weeds, what does it mean to be the one stop shop for a given set of behaviours?

Generally in software several pieces of code work together to achieve an outcome: Program works with Operating system, Functions call Functions, Libraries import libraries. Obviously not all of these fit the definition of "service" as in SOA, but then again we are being very software orientated here. What about the six servers that this service is distributed across? Do they not technically qualify as "the service" in SOA? oh, and the network cables, two switches, and the router. *...what about power and thermal management...*

Flippancy aside, that is how ill defined this is. In order to get an answer you are going to need to define what a service is.

One way of seeing this is from the perspective of a novice/lazy programmer. If they can access the information at a lower/more direct level they will. Especially if it means they can avoid The Service™. What that means is that they may change the data without the service logic correspondingly being in a correct state, or they may interpret the data differently to what the service would produce.

A good example is a table which stores reporting values. These values being pre-calculated values, that the service might dynamically adjust when asked.

Imagine a status field with: `initial, in progress, complete, error` as possibilities. The record might be in a `initial` state, but the service sees a long running task in the table so responds with `in Progress`, knowing the task will eventually update the record. That is how data can be misinterpreted quite trivially.

Imagine that the lazy programmer inserts a record directly into the table, without also adding a task to the queue for processing? The service knows to do this. But is now in a confused state, as that record will never reach `complete`.

Its simply encapsulation 101. A service is behaviour, and data inextricably linked.

---

Thought experiment:

Imagine there is a database, with data in it. That data is expected to be transformed in specific ways.

Lets imagine two programs, lets call them Service A, and Service B for now, and they are each responsible for a specific business capability.

At what point would these two separate programs stop being two distinct services, and start being one single service with two end-points?

Is it when they:

- shared a database?
- shared a schema?
- shared a table?
- shared a stored procedure?
- shared a piece of domain logic?
- shared a common library for entity mapping?
- shared a common library of entities?
- shared a common library of entity validation?
- happen to have the similarly specified entities, validation, and mappings?
- when they perform the same state transition?

I think each person will answer differently.

I personally think the line is quite hazy - but should both programs be capable of the same state transition, then clearly they are two modules of one service.

Before that you can argue they are independent services, even with the copious amounts of sharing going on, even communication between services happening through the database.

Unfortunately most of the benefits generated by SOA do not come from sharing. They instead come from isolation.

Particularly the isolation generated by having very strong boundaries afforded by a network based interface (you can't just call the hidden function in that namespace, or read the database file directly), well defined interfaces (because you have to make the bytes mean something), and the ability to use different language/libraries/os/hardware to optimise the implementation for providing the service.

Answer (score -1):

Pat Helland, from [Data on the Outside versus Data on the Inside](http://cidrdb.org/cidr2005/papers/P12.pdf)

> Services  communicate with  each  other  exclusively through messages....
>
> It is explicitly allowed (and,  indeed,  expected)  that  the  partner  service  may  be implemented  with  heterogeneous  technology  at  all  levels of   the   stack   including   hardware,   operating   system, database...
>
> The only way to interact  with  the  service  is  via  the  prescribed  messages each  of  which  will  invoke  application  logic  to  decide  if and  when  to  access  the  data  encapsulated  within  the service.  Data is, in general, never allowed out of a service unless it is processed by application logic....
>
> The use of the  word  “service” in this paper is hereby clarified to  carry  the  assumption  that  ACID  transactions  are  not shared across service boundaries

In short - each service has its own logical database.  These could be hosted on the same physical instance, but the services are proscribed from directly accessing each other's data.

Jeff Bay apparently suggested that one of the constraints of a service architecture is that you should only deploy one service at a time.  That's going to make a huge mess if you have two services sharing a database schema, when one of them needs to change it.  Of course, if each service is using only their own database schema, then they can migrate the schema any time they want.

Comment: `In short - each service has its own logical database` -- Your quoted passage doesn't say that.  All it says is that services in SOA should have well-defined boundaries, which should be self-evident.